# export_inference_graph.py vs export_tflite_ssd_graph.py

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, object-detection, object-detection-api

The output of `export_inference_graph.py` is

```
 - model.ckpt.data-00000-of-00001
 - model.ckpt.info
 - model.ckpt.meta
 - frozen_inference_graph.pb
 + saved_model (a directory)
```

while the output of  `export_tflite_ssd_graph.py`

```
- tflite_graph.pbtxt
- tflite_graph.pb
```

What is difference in both the frozen files?

Comment: It will be much helpful if you try to understand the code written in the file and ask questions based on code that you didn't understand.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are trying to use your object detection model on mobile devices. For which you need to convert your model to tflite version.
But, you cannot convert models like fasterRCNN to tflite. You need to go for SSD models to be used for mobile devices.

Another way to use model like fasterRCNN in your deployment is,
Use AWS EC2 tensorflow AMI, deploy your model on cloud and have it routed to your website domain or mobile device. When server gets an image through http form that user fills, model will process it on your cloud server and send it back to your required terminal.

Comment: Yeah, I am trying to test my model on Google coral Edge TPU. I successfully converted MobileNet SSD model to tflite. I was just wondering whether we can convert other models or not which you already answered that we can't.

Comment: Kindly have a look at edited answer, if you still want to use FasterRCNN model in your deployment.

Comment: Other models that you can try on edge are -  resnet, efficient net etc. If you are intrested in Faster rcnn model on edge tpu check this link.  
 https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/tpu_exporters/faster_rcnn.py

Comment: @Shetty that link is really helpful. Thank you.